# Python and associated Legendre polynomials

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scientific-computing

I have been searching for a python implementation of the associated Legendre polynomials quite a long time and have found nothing satisfying me. There is an implementation in `scipy.special`, but it is not vectorized. I have found a solution to use `pygsl` interface with `gsl` library, but I had a hard time to get everything compiled.

Does anyone know better solution to get access to associated Legendre polynomials in efficiently vectorized way, i.e. Legendre functions has to be applied for multidimensional matrices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[scipy.special.lpmv](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.special.lpmv.html) is vectorized.